# How to cure a "Illegal string offset" php error in an unmaintained wordpress plugin

Tags: php, string, wordpress, plugins, offset

I am not a php programmer so this is as clear as mud to me.

Wordpress plugin is WP Custom Search Version: 0.3.26  It seems to be the only remotely usable plugin that will allow me to create a multi field search form for the sidebar of a site. It works reasonably well on my WAMP installation on the office PC but throws the error below when I moved it up onto the client's hosting on a GoDaddy VPS.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'preset' in /home/clubfund/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/wp-custom-fields-search.php on line 401
```

The error appears to refer to this section of the php code.

```
function process_shortcode($atts,$content){
            return $this->generate_from_tag(array("",$atts['preset']));
        }
```

Most answers to similar questions refer to confusion between string and array values. I wouldn't know where to start despite having read through many similar questions and solutions. Unfortunately the plugin creator doesn't seem to be able to respond to questions.  I wondered if anyone here would be willing to help.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This error indeed means that `$atts` is a string, not an array. Could you trace this part of the code? How this function is called?

Comment: Yes, how is the shortcode written on site? Like `[SHORTCODE-NAME preset="something"]`... Also, show the function `generate_from_tag()`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have different error levels in production and development.  The issue is probably happening locally as well, you just don't see it being logged.  Anyways, the issue is that the array key `preset` doesn't exist in the `$atts` array.

To remedy this you could do this right above the return line -

```
if(!array_key_exists($atts, "preset"))
{
  $atts["preset"] = "";
}
```

That will set the value to an empty string if it isn't already set.

If you aren't sure what is actually being passed in, you could do something like- `var_dump($atts)` or `gettype($atts)` to see if the type is even an array.

Comment: Actually, this warning will be shown _only_ if `$atts` is a string. The important part of the puzzle is that it's only shown since PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the shortcode in your template, put the long code:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_custom_fields_search')) 
    wp_custom_fields_search(); ?>
```

I also had the same problem and already this solved it.